# JNA java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError and The specified module could not be found

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native, jna

I'm putting together a jar that will let me call commands only available to natives (the jar uses natives rather then the actual program). Now I ran into a problem, whenever I load the DLL. Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'myDLL.dll': The specified module could not be found.

at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:194)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:283)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:142)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:368)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:353)
at src.NativeBridgeJar.<clinit>(NativeBridgeJar.java:6)
at src.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

I don't why what the cause of this error would be. I made sure I set the native library path to the folder with the native. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

A) when you call [`Native.loadLibrary()`](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29), you may provide a shorthand name ("myDll"), a filename ("myDll.dll"), or the absolute path of the shared library ("c:/users/me/myDll.dll").

B) If you don't provide an absolute path to the library, you may tell it where to load the DLL by specifying `jna.library.path`, or making it available on `java.library.path` (there are other options described in the [`NativeLibrary` javadoc](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html)).

Answer (score 2):

You should show JVM your dlls location. It can be done with `-Djava.library.path=pathToDll` VM argument

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I put my .dll file into C:\Windows\System32 since it was a C++ DLL and had dependencies on Kernel32.dll and MSVCR100.dll in that folder.  That seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the path of dll using `-Djava.library.path=pathToDll` or `System.setProperty("jna.library.path","pathToDll");` make sure the specific Visual C++ xxxx Redistributable Package is installed in your Windows(bcs the windows native libraries should have been built with specific VisualStudio xxxx)